# VScode settings.json

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, debian

My understanding is that most logical way to manage my extensions ( and other stuff, I guess ) in VSCode is to edit its setting.json file. 
I am using Debian Linux MX Continuum 18.3 and based on what I have read on internet it should be found in ~/.config/Code/User, but there is no such file there.

Comment: Why don't you just open settings from the program menu?

Comment: Can't find what I am looking for there, for example keyboard combo to apply PHP-formatter to a .php file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Method #1**

Press `ctrl+shift+P` / `F1`  and search for "Preferences: Open settings (JSON)".

**Method #2**

Navigate to Preferences --> Settings --> Extensions.
Over there, choose your language, and then click on "Edit in settings.json".